# returning pairs in an array that match a certain condition

Tags: python, arrays, list

so I have to do some data processing and I am hitting a roadblock on how to properly write this once.

I have an array of integers  which can range between 0 and 400.

Now most values will be in a certain range(~100)

I want to find all values who are more than twice as big as eachother. So 2*a >= b.
E.g if you have 90 and 180. I want to find the index of those and all of those so let's say in the same array I have also a 200. Then I also want to return 90 and 200.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please include some example input and output, as well as any code that you have.

Comment: "two times apart" - based on what? Do you mean `b - a > 2 * a`?

Comment: I figured it out, and I already posted an answer, but your question should include example input and output, as well as any code you have. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should be nice to people you're asking for help, and who want to help you :).

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
from itertools import permutations


def twice_apart_pairs(data):
    for x, y in permutations(data, 2):
        if 2*x <= y:
            yield (x, y)


data = [1, 3, 6, 45, 82]

data.sort()

results = list(twice_apart_pairs(data))

print(results)
```

Results:

```
[(1, 3), (1, 6), (1, 45), (1, 82), (3, 6), (3, 45), (3, 82), (6, 45), (6, 82)]
```